# location.search alternative to remove query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and its a very simple question. I need to remove query params from the URL. So, I searched also but all the answers were pointing towards location.search (key,null) or something like this. But the problem is in my case the location only contains the user id and the passwords but not the query parameters so even if I search it is not able to find. I tried this with the URL I am forming to get the data but I was not able to remove it.

Can please anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You need give an example of how this url is formatted.
e.g.: http://username.pasword or how otherwise were unable to answer your specific question.

Comment: yes it has username and session id

Comment: I got the solution by using split I can remove query parmas...